# Filter Numpy Array with optional argument

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I am building a function which should prepare my data depending on the input. The variable `x_imp` contains indices on which features are important. However sometimes I still need all features so if 'x_imp = None' nothing should happen.

My solution was this (this is not the whole function just the inputs):

```
def get_train_data(x_cat, x_num,x_imp = None):
        x_cat = x_cat[:,x_imp]
        x_num = x_num[:,x_imp]
    return x_train
```

But this changes the shape of the data.
For example if `data.shape = (4, 5)` then `data[:,None].shape = (4, 1, 5)`

How do I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because slicing by `None` is an alias for `np.newaxis`. Is there a reason not to just add an explicit `if` statement?

```
def get_train_data(x_cat, x_num,x_imp = None):
    if x_imp is not None:
        x_cat = x_cat[:,x_imp]
        x_num = x_num[:,x_imp]
    return x_train
```